# Selenium: VSCode can't find the import

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, import, path

So i'm not sure what's going on here. I was using Sublime, which works fine with this code, but it isn't working in VSCode for some reason. I am getting told that selenium is installed (Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages) when calling python -m pip install selenium (and obviously since it's working in Sublime) but why wouldn't it be working in VSCode? Do I need to give VSCode some address to find where the file is installed? I'm on Windows, how is that done? Thanks.

Run error: PS C:\Users\andre\Projects> & C:/Users/andre/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/andre/Projects/webscraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/andre/Projects/webscraper.py", line 4, in 
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
PS C:\Users\andre\Projects>

Install error:
PS C:\Users\andre\Projects> python -m pip install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.6)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications");
chromedriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/andre/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
   with chromedriver as browser:
      browser.get(url)
```

Comment: Show us the output of `print(sys.path)`.

Comment: Also, I'm confused when you say it worked with Sublime.  Sublime is just an editor, isn't it?  Or is there a way to run code directly within Sublime?

Comment: @JohnGordon ['', 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32', 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: @JohnGordon You can build with sublime. With the default sublime (Crtl + B) build it works fine, and the code runs.

Comment: `'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages'` is in your path, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  Can you edit the question to include the full error message?

Comment: Was Sublime calling some external Python binary to do the build?  And if so, which one?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, the code is added.

Comment: @JohnGordon Well, it's using the default Sublime Python build, so yes. I'm not sure how to find the build folder though.